# Python- too many values to unpack (creating bounding box)

Tags: python, gis, valueerror

I'm attempting to generate a map of Arizona in python, intending to use the method setworldcoordinates() instead of transforming coordinates. I am writing a code to determine the bounding box by but am coming up with 
`ValueError: too many values to unpack` at the line containing `for x,y in state[POINTS]:`

I've pasted the whole code up to the for loop at the bottom that is yielding the error. For reference, the imported csv file contains 17 rows of data in 2 columns. I'm new to programming and am not sure what error I'm making or how to fix it.

```
#Importing modules 
import csv
import turtle as t

# Retrieve AZ map coordinates from a csv file
az_coords = open('AZ_points_simple.csv', "r")   # open file
csvReader = csv.reader(az_coords)               # create reader object
header = csvReader.next()                       # gives back a list of each item in header
latIndex = header.index("Y")                    # access column headers needed from file
lonIndex = header.index("X")

# Make empty list for coordinates
coordList = []

# loop through the lines in the file and get each coordinate 
for row in csvReader:
    lat = row[latIndex]             # Y coordinate
    lon = row[lonIndex]             # X coordinate
    coordList.append([lat,lon])

# DATA MODEL
# All cities will have a name, 1+ points, and population count
NAME = 0
POINTS= 1
POP = 2

# Create state layer 
state = ["ARIZONA", [coordList], 7016270]

# Cities layer list 
# city = [name, [points], population]
cities = []

# add Phoenix
cities.append(["PHOENIX", [-112.09, 33.57], 1615017])
# add Tucson
cities.append(["TUCSON", [-110.87, 32.14], 530706])
# add Flagstaff 
cities.append(["FLAGSTAFF", [-111.62, 35.19], 71459])

# MAP SIZING 
map_width = 400
map_height = 300

# State bounding box 
# Use min/max functions to get bounding box 
minx = 180 
maxx = -180 
miny = 90
maxy = -90
for x,y in state[POINTS]:
    if x < minx: 
        minx = x
    elif x > maxx: 
        maxx = x
    if y < miny:
        miny = y 
    elif y > maxy:
        maxy = y`
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
state = ["ARIZONA", [coordList], 7016270]
```

to:

```
state = ["ARIZONA", coordList, 7016270]
```

`coordList` is already a list of `x, y` pairs, leave it like that.

Comment: Can't believe it was that simple! Thank you